# How to calculate child div length from parent div; using classnames; in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The parent div have class name 'panel'.

It contains further child divs have class name 'clonablePart' and also one button.

We need to check

1) if there are multiple clonablePart then the button which is by default disable should turn enable

2) if there is one clonable part then button should remain disabled

Note: Class name 'panel' in parent div panel; can also exist in its child div's. Also 'Input' can be multiple

Please see fiddle for more details for HTML structure.
https://jsfiddle.net/k2rbs70m/

Following is JQuery in Use:

```
$('.myclass').each(function () {
        var lengthOfClones = $(this).closest('div.panel').find('.clonablePart').length;
        var typeOfClone = $(this).data("type");
        console.log('Length of Clones:' + typeOfClone + " - " + lengthOfClones); 
        lengthOfClones > 1 ? $('#delete' + typeOfClone).attr('disabled', false) : $('#delete' + typeOfClone).attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

If anything unclear please write.

Following is HTML for an idea:

```
<div id="Bank_panel" class="panel">
<div id="Bank_panel1" class="clonablePart">
    1) Bank Account
</div>
<div id="Bank_panel1" class="clonablePart">
    2) Account Name
</div>
<input type="button" value="delete" id="deleteBank"  data-type="Bank" disabled /> <i> Make it Enable onload as it have two values</i>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it could work. Is it potentially failing because you might actually have to use `removeAttr('disabled')` and `attr('disabled','true')` instead of just using `attr('disabled', :Bool )` (doesn't jQuery have a `prop` function for that)? I'm thinking that might be it. Please post some example HTML for us to check out, though, otherwise this will be hard to help with.

Comment: Could you please look into link i have attached for easy look into matter. It is link to fiddle

Comment: I have looked into it, and posted an answer. Just a reminder, though: SO has its own SO snippets which are native to SO _and_ it keeps in line with the recommendation that all code be included in the site itself so links don't break when users want to view the answers and questions later.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one `input` child per `panel` class, you can target it like this:

```
$(this).find('input')
```

In your code, this would give:

```
 lengthOfClones > 1 ? $(this).find('input').attr('disabled', false) : $(this).find('input').attr('disabled', true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggngygzy/

EDIT

IF you have more than one input child per panel, you can find a unique property and target it. Like this for example:

```
$(this).find('input[type=button]')
```

Comment: No, it is not one. Updated question.

Comment: There are multiple input type = buttons. Only with ID i can differentiate it.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue you presented in the Fiddle:

```
$('.panel').each(function () {
    // Find the button with a value of `delete`
    var button   = $(this).find("input[value='delete']");
    var clones   = $(this).find('.clonablePart');
    if(clones.length > 1) 
        button.removeAttr('disabled')
    else 
        button.attr('disabled', true) ;
});
```

The trick is: you *only* want children to be counted, so use `.find()`. Then, find the button inside your wrapper and enable and disable that by the amount of results found.

```js
//Will take outer panels only

$('.panel').each(function () {
    var button   = $(this).find("input[value='delete']");
    var clones   = $(this).find('.clonablePart');
    var type     = button.data("type");
    if(clones.length > 1) 
        button.removeAttr('disabled')
    else 
        button.attr('disabled', true) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Bank_panel" class="panel">
    <div id="Bank_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        1) Bank Account
    </div>
    <div id="Bank_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        2) Account Name
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="delete" id="deleteBank"  data-type="Bank" disabled /> <i> Make it Enable onload as it have two values</i>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="insurance_panel" class="panel">
    <div id="insurance_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        1) Insurance Account
    </div>
    <div id="insurance_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        2) Insurance Name
    </div>
  
    <div class="panel"></div> <!--Remember outer panel can have inner panel-->
    
    <input type="button" value="delete" id="deleteInsurance" data-type="insurance" disabled /> <i> Make it Enable onload as it have two values</i>
</div>

<br/>
<div id="economy_panel" class="panel">
    <div id="economy_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        1) Economy Account
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="delete" id="deleteeconomy" data-type="economy" disabled /> <i> Keep it disable</i>
</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple input type = buttons. Only with ID i can differentiate it.

Comment: There is only one `input[type=button]` in your any of your wrappers (`.panel`) thats what we are using the `find()` function to find the correct one. If you are planning on having more, a class is a better way than using IDs.

Comment: Actually in Note i have updated that input types can be multiple. It would be great if you can help me with that.

Comment: You could easily use `input[value='delete']` to find the appropriate delete button. I will update the answer, but be aware that changing your question after asking it is a big no-no as they make all the answers irrelevant and it mnakes us chase an ever changing goal.

Comment: OK. I will take care of it. Thanks

Comment: No prob. See if my updated answer works for you and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There are problem in your code 
`$(this).data("type")` always returns `Clones`, which is incorrect.

So, give a custom attribute `data-type` to each of the `div` under `.panel`, say for **Bank**, give `data-type="Bank"` and so on.

So the HTML becomes:

```
<div id="Bank_panel" class="panel" data-type="Bank">
    <div id="Bank_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        1) Bank Account
    </div>
    <div id="Bank_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        2) Account Name
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="delete" id="deleteBank"  data-type="Bank" disabled /> <i> Make it Enable onload as it have two values</i>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="insurance_panel" class="panel" data-type="Insurance">
    <div id="insurance_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        1) Insurance Account
    </div>
    <div id="insurance_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        2) Insurance Name
    </div>



    <input type="button" value="delete" id="deleteInsurance" data-type="insurance" disabled /> <i> Make it Enable onload as it have two values</i>
</div>

<br/>
<div id="economy_panel" class="panel" data-type="economy">
    <div id="economy_panel1" class="clonablePart">
        1) Economy Account
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="delete" id="deleteeconomy" data-type="economy" disabled /> <i> Keep it disable</i>
</div>
```

See the working fiddle here: "http://jsfiddle.net/k2rbs70m/7/"

Comment: There are multiple input types button in code. So with help of data-type i am getting values say BANK, and disabling button using #deleteBank. In #deleteBank is retried from data-type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
$('.panel').each(function () {
 var lengthOfClones = $(this).find('.clonablePart').length;
 var flagDisable = lengthOfClones == 1
 $(this).find("input[type='button']").prop('disabled',flagDisable);
});
```

It will fix your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/k2rbs70m/9/

Comment: What if there are multiple input type = buttons. Only with ID i can differentiate it.

Comment: you can use data attribute to differentiate it

Comment: I have already used that in My Fiddle but what changes will help me in getting final result.

Comment: Why even use a `data-type`? It clutters the HTML. You can easily find it by the `value` as it's always going to be `delete`